# ksqlDB driver support?

Tags: typeorm, go-gorm, ksqldb

Wondering if it's reasonably possible to support `ksqlDB`, and if so, what the level of effort might be.

I'd be willing to look into this further, and probably implement, but it's pretty new and it has largely sql-compliant syntax, with what looks like some extra bits that might not be easy (and maybe impossible) to implement with an ORM.

I notice that there's not really any ORMs out there for ksqlDB right now, and it's not immediately obvious if that's because ksqlDB is fairly new, or if it would be basically impossible to implement with most ORMs.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why it can't be supported. At the very least the core functionality of ORM's could be implemented for their basic queries being done in the background on materialized views in ksqlDB. On top of that, I can see special methods added that are specific to ksqlDBs new feature set.
It's possible that Confluent is already working on it as Kafka as a whole matures.